# Left orderable Group has infinite order

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

An $order$ on a set $S$ is an (anti-symmetric) relation $<$ on $G$ so that for each $a,b\in G$ exactly one of the following is true: $a<b, b<a$ or $a=b$.
A group $G$ is called left orderable if there is an order $<$
on $G$ so that whenever $a,b,g\in G$ with $a<b$, $ga<gb$. Show that
every element of a left orderable group has infinite order.

Solution Attempt 
I think that because whenever $a < b$ then for whatever $g$ I choose than $ga$ is never the identity $e$ so does this mean because it never is equal to $e$ that the order is infinite?

Comment: Some information is missing, we could take $a=b$ for all $a,b \in G$.

Comment: @user133281 But that would imply that $|G|=1$. But the question should say that every non-identity element of $G$ has infinite order.

Comment: How would that imply $|G|=1$? The only condition is that whenever $a<b$ we have $ga<gb$, which is true when we never have $a<b$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well $a=b$ for all $a,b \in G$ obviously implies $|G|=1$. Maybe you didn't write what you intended to?

Answer (score 4):

Why is $ga\neq e$? You state this without proof.

But it's much easier to prove this via a contradiction. What happens if $e<a$ and $a^n=e$?